# C++ get template type from object

Tags: c++, templates, singleton

I'm currently developing a GUI Application.
My GUI Application class is a singleton which depend on a templated Mutex and a templated event processing task.

//GUIApplication.hpp

```
#include <cassert>
template<typename Task_T, typename Mutex_T>
class GUIApplication
{
  public:
    GUIApplication()
    {
      m_pInstance = this;
    }
    static Mutex_T& getMutexInstance()
    {
      assert(nullptr != m_pInstance);
      return m_pInstance->m_GuiMutex;
    }
  private:
    inline static GUIApplication<Task_T, Mutex_T>* m_pInstance = nullptr;

    Task_T m_eventTask;
    
    Mutex_T m_GuiMutex;
};
```

Now I have some other classes which need a lock the mutex before doing stuff. However I do not want to make templates out of these other classes. Is there a way "derive" or "save" the template type from the current instance of GUIApplication.

```
//Foo.hpp
class Foo
{
  public:
  Foo();
};

//Foo.cpp
#include <mutex>
Foo::Foo()
{
  //here (obviously) the template auto argument deduction fails
  auto lock = std::scoped_lock(GUIApplication::getMutexInstance());
  //do stuff here....
}
```

Thx guys for your help :)

Comment: What do you mean by *""derive" or "save" the template type..."*?

Comment: *"I do not want to make templates out of these other classes...."* This does not make sense either. Templates can't be made/created from classes. Its the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you can't avoid ever specifying template arguments for `GUIApplication`, so `GUIApplication::getMutexInstance` cannot work.

#### (1) Building `GUIApplication` from aliases

However, clever use of aliases can help you avoid repeating yourself:

```cpp
using Mutex = std::mutex;
using Task = MyTask;
using App = GUIApplication<Task, Mutex>;

auto lock = std::scoped_lock(App::getMutexInstance());
```

#### (2) Extracting aliases from `GUIApplication`

Similarly, you can add alias members to `GUIApplication` that make it easier to extract template parameters back out of it:

```cpp
template<typename Task_T, typename Mutex_T>
class GUIApplication {
  public:
    using Task = Task_T;
    using Mutex = Mutex_T;
  // ...
};

// ...
using App = GUIApplication<MyTask, std::mutex>;
using Task = App::Task;
using Mutex = App::Mutex;
```

You frequently see this patten in the standard library, e.g. `std::string::size_type`, `std::vector::value_type`, etc.

Comment: thx this is an interesting idea. Why is Task and Mutex accessible from outside the class. I thought using is limited to the current scope (which is `class GUIApplication` in that case)

Comment: @JHeni `using` works exactly the same as `typedef` when used to define a type alias. `App::Task` simply refers to the type alias `Task` defined in the `App` scope. In (1), we're just passing type aliases into `GUIApplication`.

Comment: sorry just to clarify. I did implement your solution (2) but I'm getting compiler errors Task is undefined. Or did i misunderstand. Do I have to use 1 AND 2 together?

Comment: @JHeni no, you only need one of these. What error are you getting?

Comment: MSVC 17 is complaining about `using App = GUIApplication<Task, Mutex>;`
Task is no valid template argument.
I have copied your solution (2) to my class

Comment: `Task` in this example is a placeholder for some task type.

Comment: ah sorry, misunderstood. I thought this was refering to the task from the class
`using Task = Task_T;`
alright thx now it makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a custom type trait to grab a template parameter by index.

I've made a quick and dirty implementation that relies on `std::tuple` and `std::tuple_element_t` but you can also properly implement it without those (if so desired).

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <int I, typename T>
struct template_param;

template <std::size_t I, template <typename...> typename T, typename... TArgs>
struct template_param<I, T<TArgs...>>
{
    using type = std::remove_pointer_t<std::tuple_element_t<I, std::tuple<TArgs*...>>>;
};

template <int I, typename T>
using template_param_t = template_param<I, T>::type;
```

Then use it in code as follows:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename TTask, typename TMutex>
struct GuiApplication
{
};

struct Task;
struct Mutex;

int main()
{
    auto app = GuiApplication<Task, Mutex>{};
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<template_param_t<0, decltype(app)>, Task>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<template_param_t<1, decltype(app)>, Mutex>);
}
```

---

This will not fix your example that fails to compile though, it is merely an alternative approach to get hold of template parameters.

To actually fix your error, I prefer aliasing `GuiApplication` as suggested by [Jan Schultke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77759061/4841248) and let the compiler deduce everything.

Comment: this is an interesting idea. I'll try it out :)